# Unicode regex that do not match any letter nor any punctuation sign

Tags: regex, unicode

I am trying to create a unicode regex that matches every character except for a letter (of any language) and the punctuation signs `.;:?!`.

So for example the string

abcd 123 kjd ¤%/(" .?:!

should only match the bold parts below

abcd **123** kjd **¤%/("** .?:!

I know that `\P{L}+` matches everything except a letter and `\P{P}+` matches everything except a punctuation sign. How do I combine this two regex string to one? I have tried simply putting the together `\P{L}+\P{P}+` but this does not give the required match. I have also tried writing `[^.;:?!]\P{L}+` but this does not work either.

How do I combine one or more unicode regex or is there a better regex that achieves my requirement?

Comment: You can add add `\P{L}` to the negated character class `[^ \p{L}.;:?!]` https://regex101.com/r/7fVj9u/1

Comment: @The fourth bird Thank you, exactly what I wanted. If you want you can post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Actually, combining the two `\P{L}` and `\P{P}` patterns is `[^\p{L}\p{P}]+`, but it [does not seem to fetch your expected results](https://regex101.com/r/4Dcb8q/2). You need a subset of `\p{P}` only, so it is easier to use a custom set.

Comment: @Thefourthbird When you post an answer, it might be handy to use `\p{Z}` or `\s` instead of a regular space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\P{L}+\P{P}+` will match 1+ times the opposite of any letter followed by 1+ times the opposite of any punctuation mark.

The pattern `[^.;:?!]\P{L}+` matches 1 time any character other than the listed followed by 1+ times the opposite of any letter.

---

What you could do is add `\p{L}` (which will match any kind of letter) to the negated character class. As advised by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew), you can add `\p{Z}` to match any kind of whitespace.

```
[^\p{Z}\p{L}.;:?!]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kvk1ie/1)